# how to get multiple pages from Web activity and For Each Activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: for-loop, pagination, each

For Each Activity in Azure Data Factory Pipeline, how to copy the data from multiple pages?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HggsS.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb6Xw.png)

How to get data from pages by taking offset & limit values automatically?

Currently its only showing the data from first 25 rows (from 1st Page) only. Here problem is REST API is working with my URL. I cannot configure Pagination rule.

Any guidelines will be really helpful.

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGVtK.png)

Comment: Removed `android-activity` tag as this is not an Android question